# Open PDF in new Tab - Blazor

Tags: html, pdf, blazor

I would like to open a PDF in a new Tab. The following code works in a normal HTML File, but not in Blazor. Is there any way to use it in Blazor or is there another way to open a PDF in **Blazor**?

```html
<a href="Path" target="_blank">Read more</a>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464577/open-pdf-in-a-new-tab-in-browser

Comment: @Sergi That's MVC. Looking for Blazor way.

Comment: @MaxB - Did you solve this?

Comment: @SteveGreene Not yet.

Comment: @MaxB Any news? (Below answer does not work.)

Comment: @Flippowitsch nope unfortunately not :/

Comment: @MaxB I finally found the solution. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

What works in "normal" HTML, does not work in Blazor, because the service-worker routes unknown routes to index.html. See `onFetch()` method of service-worker.published.js:

```
const shouldServeIndexHtml = event.request.mode === 'navigate';
const request = shouldServeIndexHtml ? 'index.html' : event.request;
```

When you click your link `<a href="Path" target="_blank">Read more</a>`, the `shouldServeIndexHtml` is `true`.

To avoid this, simply change above code to

```
const shouldServeIndexHtml = event.request.mode === 'navigate'
     && !event.request.url.includes('/pdf/');
const request = shouldServeIndexHtml ? 'index.html' : event.request;
```

This assumes, that your pdfs are in a subfolder "pdf" under wwwroot. Please find more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/progressive-web-app?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#support-server-rendered-pages). Since the url includes "/pdf/", the `shouldServeIndexHtml` becomes `false` and your pdf is displayed.

Answer (score -2):

Two options I can suggest:

**Via a button.**

```
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime

<button @onclick="@LoadPage">Load Page</button>

@code {
    async Task LoadPage()
    {
        await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("open", "MyPage", "_blank");
    }
}
```

**Via a link.**

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="MyPage" target="_blank">
```

where the razor page you want to launch has the following at the top:

```
@page "/MyPage"
```

Comment: This is for routing between my Blazor pages right? But i want to open a PDF.